# Running terminal and entering Commands on Startup (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: terminal, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, startup

On startup i am trying to make The Pi open terminal run a source command "source env/bin/activate" and then run the command "google-assistant-demo' all while the terminal is still open. This part is crucial as the google assistant development software i am using requires the console to remain open.

This is for a personal assistant product i am using and i have tried creating a executable sh script on startup but that can only run one command and the terminal closes afterwards.

source env/bin/activate

google-assistant-demo

When i try to edit the startup config file the terminal opens for a second and instantly closes.

Comment: can I ask you a question? what kind of research you did in order to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

### Execute script on start-up

[Here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up) you can find a page full of wonderful solutions to run a script at the boot startup of the system. Within a script, you can do almost everything you want (for instance run the command you were speaking about `source env/bin/activate`).
[Here](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/run-command-startup-linux-27796.html) another useful link.

### How to run a Linux Program on Startup

January 2, 2017 Tim How To, Raspberry Pi

---

Here are the steps to have a program or script start on boot on a linux machine using Systemctl. I’m currently using this start several services on my raspberry pi. DigitalOcean wrote an article that goes into more detail on Systemctl.

Run this command

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/YOUR_SERVICE_NAME.service
```

Paste in the command below. Press ctrl + x then y to save and exit

```
Description=GIVE_YOUR_SERVICE_A_DESCRIPTION

Wants=network.target
After=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=YOUR_COMMAND_HERE
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reload services

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Enable the service

```
sudo systemctl enable YOUR_SERVICE_NAME
```

Start the service

```
sudo systemctl start YOUR_SERVICE_NAME
```

Check the status of your service

```
systemctl status YOUR_SERVICE_NAME
```

Reboot your device and the program/script should be running. If it crashes it will attempt to restart.

[Here](https://timleland.com/how-to-run-a-linux-program-on-startup/) the link to the original post. However, it seems that you did not check on Google (or other) before: the web is full of such information and many of them are amazing!