# Run terminal with commands after startup on Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: linux, terminal, raspberry-pi

I need to open the terminal on startup and execute three commands in the same window automatically on my Raspberry 4B. The first is a *cd* command. The second one is: *source /tflite/bin/activate*. And the last one is: *python program.py*. After executing the last one, I need to keep the program running. I've tried solutions from similar threads like: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507243/start-shell-script-on-raspberry-pi-startup) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58641120/running-terminal-and-entering-commands-on-startup-raspberry-pi) but none of them worked for me. I also tried making an sh file, which executed the commands separately and had some other issues. I've also modified the ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart file, but it didn't work.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [raspberrypi.se] would be better places for questions like this.